# Animate div off screen to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;">
  <div id="left" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div id="right" style="width: 50%; display: inline-block;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to animate the left div to width: 100% and have the right div subsequently slide off to the right.

I thought that the overflow-x: hidden would work but the right div immediately drops below the left div as soon as the left div reaches 51%.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex` inparent div and set `flex: 0 0 auto` to avoid browser trying to fit the children within the parent

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
}
#left {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 62%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#right {
  background-color: red;
  
  height: 100px;
  width:50%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
  <div id="left" > </div>
  <div id="right" > </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had not used 'flex' before.  Works a treat!  Thanks.

Comment: PS.  Any idea why overflow-x: hidden did not do the job?

Comment: @NeilW Actually the problem is not from `overflow-x: hidden`. I just realized that you can keep using `display: inline-block` but you'll have to put `white-space: nowrap` at `#container` as well so its child stays on the same line. check this https://codepen.io/krugtep/pen/zXarwZ